# Map DTO to Domain Model

Tags: c#, mapping, valueinjecter

I have a DTO as follows:

```
 class ProjectDTO{

     string Title;
     string Data;

 }
```

Then domain model as follows:

```
  class Project{
    Content Content {set;get;}

  }

  class Content{
     string Title
     string Data;

  }
```

I am using ValueInjecter. I want to Map DTO to Domain Model.

```
project.InjectFrom(projectDTO);
```

Doesnt quite work due to inner object.

How can this be done using value injecter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, I think you need to use the `FlatLoopValueInjection` type.

```
project.InjectFrom<FlatLoopValueInjection>(projectDTO);
```

Source: https://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=flattening&referringTitle=Home

**edit**

I just noticed that this only solves the exact opposite of your problem. Heh.

**edit**

Why not this?

```
project.Content.InjectFrom(projectDTO);
```

**edit**

There is also the `UnflatLoopValueInjection` type that seems to do what you need.

https://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=unflattening

The documentation is a little vague though. Seems that you have to follow some sort of naming convention in order for it to actually do anything.

```
class ProjectDTO
{
    string ContentTitle; // Project.Content.Title becomes ProjectDTO.ContentTitle
    string ContentData;  // Project.Content.Data becomes ProjectDTO.ContentData
}
```

```
project.InjectFrom<UnflatLoopValueInjection>(projectDTO);
```

Comment: Yeah the second one works after `project.Content = new Content()`.

Comment: @DarthVader I added more information based on new findings.